# Finding the expected value of a random variable.

Tags: probability

So we have some balls and $5$ urns. We put the balls one by one into the urns. Let $X_i$ denote the number of empty urns after we put the $i^{th}$ balls into the urn. What is the expected value of $X_i$?

I don't know how to get the probability mass function of $X_i$.

I was able to find the $E(X_{i+1}|X_i)$, I don't know if this help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $X_i^{(n)}$ denote the indicator random variable for the event that the $n$'th urn is still empty after the $i$'th ball was placed.

Notice that $X_i = X_i^{(1)}+X_i^{(2)}+X_i^{(3)}+X_i^{(4)}+X_i^{(5)}$ and then that $E[X_i]=\sum\limits_{k=1}^5 E[X_i^{(k)}]$ by the linearity of expectation.

We don't actually care about finding the exact pmf for this scenario to answer the stated problems.